# Administrative rights: Winforms vs WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, uac

I have been porting a Winforms app to WPF and have noticed the following regarding administrative rights. 
The application launches a command line exeternal app as part of its execution using 'ProcessStartInfo'. The Winforms app has no application manifest and runs the app correctly.
However the WPF version won't launch the external app correctly UNLESS I give the WPF application administrative rights. ()

I'd prefer not to do this because of the somewhat annoying UAC confirmation dialog.
I've tried adding the 'ProcessStartInfo' Verb = "runas" but that has no effect.

Does anyone know why the Winforms version is OK but the WPF version requires admin rights? FYI. The external app process a file and writes the output file into a folder in the programdata directory)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that external process launched from Wpf apps don't have access to the ProgrammData folder, although the parent app does. (Yes I do actually need to write to folders within PrgrammData. I have system services that need to consume data and these services have no knowledge of users...)

By having the external app write to Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData and then have the parent app move the files from Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData  to programdata... things work as in the Winforms apps

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to modify your original question, then delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to Program Files is not advised. If you have control over those system services, modify them to take the data from `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` folder, this location is not user-specific and shared across the system. Then your executable will write its output to `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

---

Where ProgramData is located? If it's under Program Files, then both your WinForms and WPF applications should have administrator rights to write to it.

Comment: Alexy, I'm not attempting to write to Program Files at all. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData IS the moniker that refers to the folder ProgramData under Windows7

Comment: @user457588, were the default permissions changed on this folder, of the folder where your second app writes its output? Does your old WinForms combination still works fine on the same machine?

Look at permissions of the folder your app writes data and permissions of those files. It could shed a light on the issue.

Comment: @user457588 You have to check access permissions on the folders to which your parent app and external processes need to have write access. You may need to modify the default permissions to ensure everything works as expected, this should be done in installer.